# How do I simulate a right click using Selenium 2 and PHPUnit?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2, phpunit

I am trying to execute a functional test using Selenium 2 and PHPUnit.

In the class 'Selenium2TestCase.php', I found this code:

```
class PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_SessionCommand_Click extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_Command
{
    const LEFT = 0;
    const MIDDLE = 1;
    const RIGHT = 2;

    public function __construct($argument, PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_URL $url)
    {
        if (is_null($argument)) {
            $jsonParameters = NULL;
        } elseif (!is_scalar($argument) || !in_array($argument, array(
            self::LEFT, self::RIGHT, self::MIDDLE
        ))) {
            throw new BadMethodCallException('Wrong parameter for click(): expecting 0, 1 or 2.');
        } else {
            $jsonParameters = array('button' => $argument);
        }

        parent::__construct($jsonParameters, $url);
    }

    public function httpMethod()
    {
        return 'POST';
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to use it to simulate a right click.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function testItemClick() {

    $this->url($this->pageUrl);
    sleep(2);
    $element = $this->byCssSelector('blabla');
    $this->moveto($element);
    $this->click(PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_SessionCommand_Click::RIGHT);
    $this->assertStringStartsWith(...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use contextMenu method:

```
$this->contextMenu(//table[@id='yourID']);
```

See http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html#contextMenu

Comment: This is for the old Selenium RC, this does not work in the latest webdriver, I think.

Comment: thx Niels, I updated the answer with link to newest release.

Answer (score 0):

The [php-webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) project on GitHub has a function contextClick() which fires a right click.